# How to serialize a custom formatted time to/from xml in Go?

Tags: xml, go, formatting, date-formatting

When serializing a datetime to/from xml how do I make it use a custom time format?

Comment: Could you include a specific example of the format you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang XML Unmarshal and time.Time fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301149/golang-xml-unmarshal-and-time-time-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you'd implement `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler` for doing this with JSON (there are many posts about that on StackOverflow and the internet);
one way is to implement a custom time type that implements [`encoding.TextMarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextMarshaler) and [`encoding.TextUnmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextUnmarshaler).

Those interfaces are used by `encoding/xml` when encoding items (after first checking for the more specific `xml.Marshaler` or `xml.Unmarshaler` interfaces, however those later ones have to do full XML encoding themselves).

E.g. something like ([full example on the <kbd>Go Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/qgLIu2FbV9)):

```
const fixedFormat = "Mon Jan 02 2006"

type myTime1 struct {
    time.Time
}

func (m myTime1) MarshalText() ([]byte, error) {
    text := m.Time.Format(fixedFormat)
    return []byte(text), nil
}
func (m *myTime1) UnmarshalText(text []byte) error {
    t, err := time.Parse(fixedFormat, string(text))
    if err == nil {
        m.Time = t
    }
    return err
}
```

or

```
type myTime2 time.Time

func (m myTime2) MarshalText() ([]byte, error) {
    text := time.Time(m2).Format(fixedFormat)
    return []byte(text), nil
}
func (m *myTime2) UnmarshalText(text []byte) error {
    t, err := time.Parse(fixedFormat, string(text))
    if err == nil {
        *m = myTime2(t)
    }
    return err
}
```

Either of those can be used in place of `time.Time` as part of a larger data structure used with xml (un)marshalling. E.g.:

```
type Foo struct {
    Date1 myTime1 `xml:"date1"`
    Date2 myTime2 `xml:"date2"`
}
```

The difference in how these custom time types are defined changes how you use them with regular `time.Time` values.
E.g.

```
m1 := myTime1{time.Now()}
fmt.Println(m1)
if m1.Before(time.Now()) {}
t1 := m1.Time
// compared to:
m2 := myTime2(time.Now())
fmt.Println(time.Time(m2))
if time.Time(m2).Before(time.Now()) {}
t2 := time.Time(m2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your format looks like, but a good starting point should be the time library. http://golang.org/pkg/time/

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
str := "2014-11-12T11:45:26.371Z"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(t)
```