# Unmarshal Nested xml with Go

Tags: xml, go, nested, unmarshalling

I have the following snippet of code that I have been banging my head on the wall trying to make it work.  I have searched everywhere for a solution, but none of the ones that I have found seem to work.

It seems that I have an issue with my mapping for the `xml.Unmarshal` command as it pertains to nested fields.  The code below works for retrieving the first value which is called `unit`, and is on the top level of the xml code.

The other two fields come up as zero, and they are nested two level deep.  That implies that the structure isn't set up correctly.  Here is the code.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type datevalue struct {
    Date  int     `xml:"date"`
    Value float32 `xml:"value"`
}

type pv struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name  `xml:"series"`
    Unit       string    `xml:"unit"`
    datevalues datevalue `xml:"values>dateValue"`
}

func main() {
    contents := `<series>
                   <timeUnit>DAY</timeUnit>
                   <unit>Wh</unit><measuredBy>INVERTER</measuredBy>
                   <values><dateValue>
                        <date>2015-11-04 00:00:00</date>
                        <value>5935.405</value>
                   </dateValue></values>
                </series>`

    m := &pv{}
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(contents), &m)
    fmt.Printf("%s %f %d\n", m.Unit, m.datevalues.Value, m.datevalues.Date)
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Wh 0.000000 0
```

Comment: I don't see a question here....

Comment: You're ignoring the error from unmarshal, you're trying to unmarshal a date into an int, and the `datevalues` field isn't exported so it's not seen by the xml package.

Answer (score 12):

**First**  of all your code doesn't work because you should use **exported** fields for marshalling/unmarshalling (see https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/).
You should use

```
type pv struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name  `xml:"series"`
    Unit       string    `xml:"unit"`
    Datevalues datevalue `xml:"values>dateValue"`
}
```

instead of

```
type pv struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name  `xml:"series"`
    Unit       string    `xml:"unit"`
    datevalues datevalue `xml:"values>dateValue"`
}
```

Look at DateValues field name. If first symbol is uppercased it's will be exported. Otherwise that field will be ignored while `Unmarshal`

**Second:**

After it I noticed that you are ignoring your errors. Please don't ignore them, they are critically useful.

Check it out on the <kbd>[go playgroung](http://play.golang.org/p/6vqtSRhRcv)</kbd>

As you can see you use `int` datatype for `Date` field of `datatype`.
If you change type to `string`, your code will work.

**Third:**

I think you really want to unmarshall your `date` value into `time.Time`.
To do so you can check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301149/golang-xml-unmarshal-and-time-time-fields)

The complete working code you can try on the <kbd>[go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/l8qdPXy2KR)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I didn't realize that the fields within the struct had to be exported in order to work.