# How to parse nested JSON into structs in Go?

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

How can I map a nested JSON to a nested Struct like this:

```
type ChildStruct1 struct {
    key3,
    key4,string
}
type ChildStruct2 struct {
    key4,
    key5,string
}

type MainStruct struct {
    key1,
    key2,string
    childStruct1 ChildStruct1
    childStruct2 ChildStruct1
}
```

Input JSON:

```
{
  key1: val1,
  key2: val2,
  chilDStruct1 : {
                     key3: val3,
                     key4: val4,
                }
  chilDStruct2 : {
                     key5: val5,
                     key6: val6,
                }
}
```

How can this be mapped. I have used jsonMapper in Java but not sure how to do it here. I tried this but this is not working:

```
var data MainStruct
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("jsonData.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(file, &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data.key1)
```

I tried this also:

```
u := &MainStruct{}
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("jsonData.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), u)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(u.key1)
```

But output is always `0`.

Comment: Duplicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557401/unmarshal-nested-xml-with-go/33560897#33560897 You should **export**  your fields. Look at first part of the answer

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/Zwj3iMWdOw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite some errors in your example (both in JSON text and source code). Let's fix them.

#### JSON text

First your JSON is not valid. Try this instead of yours:

```
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "childStruct1" : {
        "key3": "val3",
        "key4": "val4"
    },
    "childStruct2" : {
        "key5": "val5",
        "key6": "val6"
    }
}
```

#### Go type definitions

Second, your Go source defining your struct types has syntax errors.

Third, you have to export struct fields in order so the `json` package can set their values. Try this instead of yours:

```
type ChildStruct1 struct {
    Key3 string
    Key4 string
}

type ChildStruct2 struct {
    Key4 string
    Key5 string
}

type MainStruct struct {
    Key1         string
    Key2         string
    ChildStruct1 ChildStruct1
    ChildStruct2 ChildStruct2
}
```

#### Code to parse the JSON text

And now on to the code to parse the JSON text. You can read the whole file into memory using [`ioutil.ReadFile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile), but often it is more efficient to not read the whole file but to "stream" it to a decoder (using the file as the input).

[`os.Open()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) returns a [`*File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File). It is not a `[]byte`, but it implements [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). So you can't pass it to [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal). Instead create a [`json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) using [`json.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder) which accepts an `io.Reader`, so you can pass the opened file. And don't forget to close the opened file using [`File.Close()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Close), best to close it as a deferred statement (if opening it succeeds).

```
f, err := os.Open("jsonData.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

var data MainStruct
err = json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(&data)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(data.Key1)
fmt.Printf("%+v", data)
```

(Note that I used [`log.Panic()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Panic) instead of [`log.Fatal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal) as the latter calls [`os.Exit()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit) and hence our deferred function would not be called.)

Output:

```
val1
{Key1:val1 Key2:val2 ChildStruct1:{Key3:val3 Key4:val4} ChildStruct2:{Key4: Key5:val5}}
```

#### Modified version for the Go Playground

Here is a modified version that parses the JSON text from a constant defined in the source code, try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SLUWd3p7oQ):

```
var data MainStruct
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(data.Key1)
fmt.Printf("%+v", data)
```

#### Final notes

Keys in the JSON text start with lowercase letters, struct field names in Go start with uppercase letters (needed in order to be exported), but the `json` package is "clever" enough to match them. Should you use something different, you could use [tags](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Tag) to specify how a struct field can be found in the json, e.g.

```
type ChildStruct1 struct {
    Key3 string `json:"myKey3"`
    Key4 string `json:"myKey4"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works perfectly..Awesome explanation too.

Comment: The internal keys of child struct are not populayted

Comment: @SankalpMishra There was a typo in the code, which I already fixed. Please copy the current version of the code and it will work.